# How can I address missing values for LSTM?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, dataset, data-mining, lstm

I'm a student and writing my first paper for submission on a conference. I have a question

There is a dataset below. this is temporal-spatial dataset.

```
Date         Hour   City       Sensor1  Sensor2  Sensor3 Sensor4 ...
21-06-10     0      Region1      0.12     0.52    0.33     0.44  ...
21-06-10     1      Region2      0.16     0.83    0.34     0.49  ...
21-06-10     2      Region1      0.21     0.44    0.57     0.5   ...
...
```

My task is anomaly detection for each region.

I want to use LSTM. So, I represent the temporal-spatial data to two time-series data. my dataset can be represented below.

```
City       Date       Hour     Sensor1  Sensor2  Sensor3 Sensor4 ...
Region1   21-06-10     0         0.12     0.52    0.33     0.44  ...
Region1   21-06-10     2         0.21     0.44    0.57     0.5   ...
...


City       Date       Hour     Sensor1  Sensor2  Sensor3 Sensor4 ...
Region2   21-06-10     1         0.16     0.83    0.34     0.49  ...
...
```

However, then, there is no a row with attribute '*Hour=1*' in Region1 data
(you can see the table below)

```
City       Date       Hour     Sensor1  Sensor2  Sensor3 Sensor4 ...
Region1   21-06-10     0         0.12     0.52    0.33     0.44  ...
Region1   21-06-10     1         NaN      NaN     NaN      NaN   ...
Region1   21-06-10     2         0.21     0.44    0.57     0.5   ...
...
```

Can I insert estimated values into the row with attribute '*Hour=1*' in Region1 data? (for example, I want to insert mean values for each attribute between the first row and the third row)

Then, can I claim to have utilized a real world dataset even with this missing value estimation?

Comment: Is it not easier to just remove the row?

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch If removing the row, this can not be time-series form. I know LSTM is suitable for time-series form

Comment: I think my input have to have same time interval